How to apply visualization for each node in OMNet++?
I have created a network of nodes in OMNet++. I have defined in Network.ned:
visualizer:  <default(firstAvailableOrEmpty("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer"))> like IIntegratedVisualizer if typename != "" {@display("p=38,168");}` 

I am able to access the Network module and change the parameter in the runtime.
cModule* cNode=subjectModule->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("visualizer")->getSubmodule("mobilityVisualizer"); 
cNode->par("displayPositions").setBoolValue(true); 
cNode->par("positionCircleLineColor").setStringValue("red");
cNode->par("positionCircleFillColor").setStringValue("red");

With this I actually all the nodes positions colored red. But actually I want only some of the nodes to be colored red & rest green based on condition.
